# Determine if 2nd or 4th Monday of the Month

Tags: batch-file

Need to break out the good old batch file.
It's there a way to find out if it's the 2nd or 4th Monday of the month?

So if it's not the 2nd or 4th Monday run this command. If it is the 2nd or 4th Monday of the month then exit.

Comment: Is javascript or vbscript allowed or must it be done entirely in batch?

Comment: @cup they want to attempt to keep it in the batch file that is running other scripts. I could write this easily using something else so if I can't get it figured out then they won't have a choice lol.

Comment: @Tsukasa you have to choose any programming language in your question

Comment: @Leo batch files / windows shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the functionality that will do this for you.  First we need to find out what the current `day of the week` is and the `day number`.  Then we need to use some `if` `else` statements based on the `day` to see if it's the second or fourth Monday.  There is most likely an easier way to do this, but this should work:

```
@echo off
:: Formatting Date and Time
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%d in ('echo %date%') do (
    set dow=%%d
    set month=%%e
    set day=%%f
    set year=%%g
)


:: Picking the 2th and 4th Monday
if "%dow%"=="Mon" (
    if %day% geq 8 if %day% leq 14 (
        echo INFO: Today is the Second Monday
        goto end
    )
)

if "%dow%"=="Mon" (
    if %day% geq 22 if %day% leq 28 (
        echo INFO: Today is the Fourth Monday
        goto end
    )
)

:: add the command lines that you want to run on any other day than the 2nd and 4th Monday
echo INFO: It's not the 2nd or 4th Monday on the Month

:end
```

Comment: This is working with the 4th Monday of the Month but not the second. Tried multiple months.

Comment: for some reason it's not entering 'if "%day%" geq "8"' dow=Mon day=12 which is greater than or equal to 8 or even 9 when it was there but for some reason it doesn't see this as being true

Comment: I'm getting the same thing when I test it.  This is weird

Comment: edited again: try the new change.  Looks like it doesn't like the punctuation

Comment: I had to remove the quotes and it evaluated correctly